# j2me: how to open application page via ovi store app

Tags: java-me, nokia, midp, ovi

I'd like to ask users to rate my app.
I can open an url in browser:

```
final String url = "http://store.ovi.com/content/168792";
MyMidlet.this.platformRequest(url);
```

But if the ovi store app is installed on the phone, I'd like to use it like in android I can start activity with Android Market intent as a parameter.
Is there any way to open my application page via ovi store app?

I'm using
CLDC-1.1
MIDP-2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Nokia Store is installed, then opening the above URL in the browser will cause the Store client to open on the specified app.